# RxJava re-create observable onError

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, subscriber, reactivex

So I have my `form` model which holds all data I want to validate and then send to the server. Let's keep it as simple as possible - `isFormValid` or api request should return `Observable.errr(throwable)` which should call `onError()` in the `subscriber`.

```
public void submitForm(Form form){
    Observable
    .just(form)
    .flatMap(form->{
        if(isFormValid(form))
            return Observable.just(form);
        else
            return Observable.error(someValidationError);
    })
    .flatMap(form->{
        Request req = new Request(form);
        try{
            return Observable.just(getResponseFrom(req));
        }
        catch(ApiException e){
            return Observable.error(e)
        }
    }).subscribe(
        new Subscriber<ResponseModel>(){
            @Override
            public void onComplete(){}
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t){}
            @Override
            public void onNext(ResponseModel model){}
        }
    );
}
```

Ok, now let's say user enters invalid data, `submitForm()` is called and -sure enought- `onError` is called in `subscriber` and then `onComplete`. The user then enters valid data and `submitForm()` is called again.

Now here's the problem - in the second `submitForm()` call nothing happens! At least `flatMap` `Func1` and the second `flatMap` `Func2` are not called. 
Why? What am I doing wrong ? Is it an architectural flaw?

Comment: Not sure why you need `flatMap`, it looks like `map` would work the same here.

Comment: Because I want to have an ability to raise a proper error via `Observable.error()`. You think throwing an exception would be better? Would it still result in calling `onError`?

Comment: You are taking a single Observable from `just`, so `flatMap` simply isn't the correct operation. Do you just want to "discard" some invalid forms and throw an error and emit the rest?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. It should work as you expect. Are you sure `submitForm` is called the second time?

Comment: @cricket_007 in a word yes, the only difference is that I will emit always one `form` (whenever `submitForm()` is called). @Egor yes, I'm also tried unsubscribing althought it should not be required as `onError` is followed by `onCompleted`

Comment: So I played around with a simple Rx stream, and any errors that occur will end the Observable at the `onComplete` method. Maybe that is what you are experiencing when the second call doesn't happen.

Comment: Ok figured out what was wrong. In my project I tried to use the same instance of `Subscriber` instead of creating a new one (like in the example). Switched to `Observer` and everything works fine now. Also got rid of `flatMaps` replacing them with `map` and using `throw Exceptions.propagate` instead. Cheers!